# Class Fields to XML Element and attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following class that I want to serialize to an XML file

```
public class HDLCParameters
{
    [XmlElement("ClientMACAddress")]
    public string ClientMACAddress { get; set; }
}
```

this is serialized like this:

```
 <HDLCParameters>
     <ClientMACAddress>0x10</ClientMACAddress>
 </HDLCParameters>
```

but i need it like this:

```
<HDLCParameters>
     <ClientMACAddress value="0x10" />
</HDLCParameters>
```

Do i need to create a ClientMACAddress class with a "value" field? isn't there a way to set an element and an attribute with its value?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the ClientMACAddress class, give it a value field, and specify that it's an attribute (XmlAttributeAttribute)

Comment: I've just posted a small example from the class. the original class has lots fields just like ClientMACAddress, i would need to create lots of classes.

Comment: Create a complex type which has a value attribute. Then use elements like <xs:element name="ClientMACAddress" type="valueAttrType"/>. Then, in your code, all these value instances will be defined in the same class, and you can write helper functions for it.